# IntelliJ Run/Debug console window

Tags: intellij-idea, console

I've been using IntelliJ 2019 and now i updated to 2020 and console window is with two sub-window instead of only one big output window.
I want to remove sub-window from the left and only remain with right sub-window because everytime execution fail it will move like ss and it will better show all console output of maven run configuration. I don't see any option to disable

[See screenshoot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5q5M.png)

Could you please help me?
Thanks
Best regards.

Comment: This is how IntelliJ shows test runs. When debugging/running your app without issuing tests, you won't get this split windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to disable this view. Please vote for the related request: [IDEA-217959](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217959).